# tmutil remove old timemachine backups but does not free space

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, time-machine, big-sur

I have BigSur 11.2.3 and my TimeMachine ran out of space, so I was trying to delete old backups from storage for some extra spaces.

As usual, here is list of backup [image]

I ran `sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/Sabrent -t 2021-08-08-170818` and it was successful.
[image]
I go into Finder and verified
[image]

yet, the storage still has same amount of space taken by something invisible (I assume the backup did not get deleted)

It seems like the command only deleted shortcut or pointer to the backup files not the backup itself.

[image]

The command used to work with previous macOS, i searched a while on google, but did not find any useful solution. Does anyone know how to properly delete a timemachine backup now? or maybe a useful GUI tool?

Comment: Why did you need to erase the Backup in the first place? Usually TM removes old backups by itself in order to do new ones.

Comment: no, TM does not automatically remove oldest backup, that's why i have to manually do it. TM never removes oldest backup for me ever since I started using macOS decade ago.

Comment: Time Machine does remove the oldest backup, unless it's also the most recent. I can confirm it does this since ... it does it on mine. Also: the fact it says "The oldest backups are deleted when your disk becomes full". You will never see it do this unless the storage disk is completely full (yours is not).

Comment: im not sure, but mine never does it, i used 4 or 5 mac machines so far, every time when storage is full, it tells me no space and backup process just stops

Comment: Deleting the oldest backup will only increase free space by the difference between that backup and the next one - and that may be small.

Comment: well if one backup is not enough, then i will delete two backups, not much choice.....

Comment: How big is the volume it is trying to back up?

Comment: its 512G volume

Comment: Maybe you should update the system first. The current version of Big Sur is 11.5.1

Comment: it has nothing to do with system version, i have another mac on 11.5.1, same thing